# Sending a value in context to all template renderd in Django without sending in context in every view

Tags: python, django

Suppose I have a variable in my settings.py file. Now I want this value to be accessed in all the templates all over the project. But I don't want to send this value in the context-data in every view. I want to send other data in context just like normally. But this specific one to be accessed in all templates. Is there any such process in Django?

For a little clarification, I wanted to implement the idea of "Interceptor" which we use to manipulate "HTTP" ajax requests.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can define a template context processor as described in [here](http://www.webforefront.com/django/setupdjangocontextprocessors.html):

**context_processors.py**

```
from django.conf import settings

def interceptor(request):
    return {'interceptor': settings.HTTP_AJAX_INTERCEPTOR}
```

**settings.py**

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    ...
    'project.context_processors.interceptor',
)
```

**base.html**

```
<html>
 ...
 <body>
  <div>{{ interceptor }}</div>
  ...
 </body>
</html>
```

Please see [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors) for more information.